# Meteor Iron Router default route notFound

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have created a meteor app using iron router and the default router looks like this

```
Router.route('/', {
this.render('Ft');
});
```

However when i load `http://localhost:3000/` i constantly get `no found` and thus the template `Ft` is not being loaded.

How can i define the default route in my application?.

Secondly,i have a controller function which looks like this

```
 home: function() {
   this.render('Ft');
  },
```

How can i define a controller function that can handle `/` which is lie the index controller function?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an object:

```
Router.route('/',{
  name: 'home',
  template: 'Ft',
  controller(){
    /* your controller function. You don't need to render in that controller 
       if you define the template above */
  }
});
```